# how to get my own android bluetooth mac address

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to get my device's own bluetooth mac address, in an android native application,
I've read (in several sources) that I can no longer get that starting from android marshmallow.
So, is there a workaround (can't seem to find that anywhere) or another unique identifier that I can get (I need that identifier to be accessible on other devices just by discovering them, without pairing to them).
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are workarounds but none of them work 100% and are not guaranteed to work in future android updates.

Comment: could you please provide me with one that is working, couldn't find any